# Stacked Observers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to know if any of nine blocks, in a 3x3 wall, are updated.  Right now I just put a 3x3 wall of observers.  I only need one output signal saying "Yes, one of the 9 blocks were updated".  e.g., piece of my wall was broken.

So right now, directly behind the wall, I put a 3x3 wall of observers.  But I can only pull signals from the bottom three observers.  The stacked observers GIVE a signal, but I have no way to retrieve that signal.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick. The top and bottom rows are powering blocks, which in turn, power the redstone line.
[image: 1 output from a 3x3 wall of observers]